# How to use linked server with stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

Anyone have an idea about how to use  to view a stored procedure on a linked server?  I don't have the credentials to that linked server to look at it. ??

Comment: I also would like to look at facebook's db schema, but I haven't access there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the server, then you can't view anything.  If you have execute permissions on the stored procedure, then sure, you can execute it.  I believe the syntax is something like

```
exec "linkName"."dbname"."schema"."procedure"
```